# DefaultCPUAllocator: not enough memory: you tried to allocate 364742208 bytes. Buy new RAM

Tags: python, memory, pytorch

I am running a pytorch NLP model in python and I keep encountering the following strange error:

```
RuntimeError: [enforce fail at ..\c10\core\CPUAllocator.cpp:75] data. DefaultCPUAllocator: not enough 
memory: you tried to allocate 364742208 bytes. Buy new RAM!
```

This is strange considering I have 16GB of RAM and the allocation is only 0.3GB. So I fail to understand the memory error.

Any help on the above will be appreciated.

Comment: Try to check the NUM_WORKERS value. It is probable that each thread tries to allocate 300Mb thus vey quickly filling up your ram and leading to the error. More code is needed to fully solve the issue

Comment: You're not using a 32-bit version of Python, are you?

Comment: @TheD0ubleT I can't seem to find the NUM_WORKERS. I would like to add I have been working with a pre trained model. I am happy to provide any code needed.

Comment: @MarkRansom No, I am using a 64-bit version.

Comment: how much batch size you assign to dataloader argument . please share more code.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Niro Please note, I am using a pertained model. Please find below the code for the same:                                                                                                                                       
import torch
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSequenceClassification
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("ProsusAI/finbert")
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("ProsusAI/finbert")

Answer (score 1):

If you have enough VRAM memory, try to increase the pagefile (virtual memory) size. The better option is to set 'System managed', or [manually increase it to higher values.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3LgH.png)