# NLP Pytorch python - [enforce fail at .path] data. DefaultCPUAllocator: not enough memory: you tried to allocate 157079520 bytes

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

This post links directly to this post: [DefaultCPUAllocator: not enough memory: you tried to allocate 364742208 bytes. Buy new RAM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67522026/defaultcpuallocator-not-enough-memory-you-tried-to-allocate-364742208-bytes-b) which an ex-colleague and friend posted on my behalf.

I wanted to follow on from this and give more detail and an example of where this happens as it's a problem I am constantly coming across whilst running NLP models in python, with still no solution.

It has occurred whilst using BERT models for sentiment analysis and the latest problem has come whilst doing backtranslation using the MarianMT model library on transformers library. It always occurs when using a Pytorch based architecture. Link to model: https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main/model_doc/marian

I am trying to translate a list of around 130 English sentences to `kwn` and then back to `en`. My sentence data are private but I'm sure a list of any 130 sentences would give the same result. Here is my code:

```
from transformers import MarianMTModel, MarianTokenizer


def format_sentence(target_lang, s):
    text = f'>>{target_lang}<< {s}'
    return text

def translate(current, target, text):
    model_name = f'Helsinki-NLP/opus-mt-{current}-{target}'
    tokenizer_current = MarianTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
    model_current = MarianMTModel.from_pretrained(model_name)
    tr = model_current.generate(**tokenizer_current(text, return_tensors="pt", padding=True))
    translated = [tokenizer_current.decode(t, skip_special_tokens=True) for t in tr]
    return translated

def simple_translate(current, target, text):
    text = [format_sentence(target, s) for s in text]
    try:
        first = translate(current, target, text)
        back = translate(target, current, first)
        return back
    except Exception as e:
        pass


sents = [YOUR LIST OF 130 ENGLISH SENTS HERE]
simple_translate('en', 'kwn', sents)
```

As the question shows once again I get this error:

```
[enforce fail at ..\c10\core\impl\alloc_cpu.cpp:81] data. DefaultCPUAllocator: not enough memory: you tried to allocate 157079520 bytes.
```

It is trying to allocate 0.146292 GB which is nothing and I can't understand why this is failing. I have also had it before where it has tried to allocated 14 GB for the same medium sized sentences which seems bizarre.

The error isn't helpful and doesn't really point to the problem. Is it an underlying architecture problem? Is it a cacheing/memory problem? Is it an issue with threading? Can it be solved by batching the sentences into a Dataloader?

I'd really like to try and pin point the problem here and looking at my original (very bare so apologies) post it seems to be a popular issue.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I would recommend batching the sentences. Does it fail with 1/5/10/30 sentences? Btw, the error isn't that it tried to allocate 0.14GB in total, it's that it needed an extra 0.14GB and couldn't allocate it.

Comment: Great thanks. Should I batch with a DataLoader, as don't they need labels with I don't have?

Comment: @jhso forgot to tag you in the above

Comment: A dataloader is good for prefetching data from a dataset. They return whatever the dataset object returns in a collated object, so they can return only the sentences if the labels don't exist. Simply batching the sentences in a for loop might be good enough for this purpose.